# Creating HTTP Header parameters in a SOAP interface in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http, soap

Can you tell me how to create a SOAP HTTP parameter in C#.  I am not talking about the SOAP HEADER within the SOAP envelope, but the HTTP header.  For example I have the Username and Password in the Header below:

```
POST /company/addThing HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.foo
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.6.2
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 295
Username: userx
Password: passwordy
```

I can add the parameters in PHP using the stream_context parameter of the SoapClient call, but I cannot find where to do it in .Net C#.

I have added the web Reference WSDL which has auto created the objects and methods for the web service and I'm comfortable with that part.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit

I've ticked the answer below, but it only works for .Net 4.0 and above.  One thing I failed to mention was that I am using Visual Studio 2008.

The final solution I used was to add the following code to the auto generated           Reference.cs file:

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    request.Headers.Add("Username", "user");
    request.Headers.Add("Password", "pass");
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a web reference from the WSDL it will generate a class for you that you use to make the calls to your service, let's call it "MyService". If you create a partial for that class, and include it in the same assembly, you can override the "GetWebRequest" method and directly add headers. Here's an example:

```
public partial class MyService
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public void SetRequestHeader(string headerName, string headerValue)
    {
        this.requestHeaders.AddOrUpdate(headerName, headerValue, (key, oldValue) => headerValue);
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        var httpRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (httpRequest != null)
        {
            foreach (string headerName in this.requestHeaders.Keys)
            {
                httpRequest.Headers[headerName] = this.requestHeaders[headerName];
            }
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```